Granger causality test with I(1) and I(2) variables
I have two time series variables for daily financial data: "A" is I(1) and "B" is I(2). After log-differencing once and twice, respectively, to make them stationary, I obtained "d_A" and "dd_B."
Assuming I have two equations with these two endogenous variables, "d_A" and "dd_B," can I use them for a Granger-causality estimation, or is it not recommended?
Any relevant literature would be helpful as well.

Have you considered the possibility that A and d_B are cointegrated?

Thank you for the insightful comment. Both parametric and non-parametric cointegration tests indicate that the two variables are not cointegrated.
